# How to update value with 'With' clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-update, common-table-expression

I would like to update the column of a table based on the result that is inside the 'With' clause. When I use tb in the update statement, it display invalid object name as it is already inside the 'With' clause. If anyone could help me on this. Thank you!

```
;WITH Split_Segments AS 
(
    SELECT 
        W.ROW_ID
    FROM 
        table1 W
    WHERE
        W.ERRORS IS NULL AND W.UserName = @userId
),
tb AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        ROW_ID, AP
    FROM 
        Split_Segments 
    WHERE 
        LEN(AP) <> 3  
)
SELECT 
    A.ROW_ID
INTO 
    #tempTable
FROM
    Split_Segments  A
INNER JOIN 
    table4 B ON A.ROW_ID = B.ROW_ID
             AND A.AP = B.AP
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tb Z ON A.ROW_ID = Z.ROW_ID
WHERE 
    Z.AP IS NULL;
```

I would like to run following statement:

```
UPDATE W SET ERRORS = 'Error' 
FROM table5 W
INNER JOIN tb T ON W.ROW_ID = T.ROW_ID
WHERE AP IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what your table data looks like, as well as what your expected output should be? I understand that it's an update statement, but it would be helpful to know what should be updated within `table5`.

Comment: Actually, I would like to update the ERRORS column only of table5. I just want to be able to use the tb that is inside the With clause so that I can inner join in the update statement as shown above. I hope it is clear. Thank you.

Comment: You can only run one select statement after your CTEs - do you also need the `Select A.ROW_ID...` portion of your code?  If so, you will need to make that another CTE.

Comment: At the moment, when I use tb in the update statement, it display invalid object name.

Comment: You would need to replace `SELECT 
  A.ROW_ID
FROM
  table3 A` with your `UPDATE` statement instead. Or change the final `SELECT` in the CTE to create another Table Expression if you need the data in it as part of the `UPDATE`.

Comment: @APH, would you mind giving an example? It will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 1):

You can only run one `SELECT` or `UPDATE` at the end of a `WITH` statement. Since you have specified that you need access to `#tempTable` outside of this CTE clause, but that table relies on `tb` for its construction, I would suggest moving `tb` to a temp table as well:

#### Remove tb from within the WITH clause:

```
 --Provisioning tb as temp table outside of CTE
 SELECT DISTINCT 
   ROW_ID, 
   AP
 INTO tb
 FROM table2
 WHERE LEN(AP) <> 3;

--Provisioning temp table outside of CTE
SELECT A.ROW_ID
INTO #tempTable
FROM table3 A
  INNER JOIN table4 B ON A.ROW_ID = B.ROW_ID
    AND A.AP = B.AP
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tb Z ON A.ROW_ID = Z.ROW_ID
WHERE Z.AP IS NULL;

WITH Split_Segments AS (
    SELECT 
      W.ROW_ID
    FROM 
      table1 W
    WHERE
      W.ERRORS IS NULL AND W.UserName = @userId)

UPDATE W SET ERRORS = 'Error' 
FROM table5 W
  INNER JOIN tb T ON W.ROW_ID = T.ROW_ID
WHERE AP is not null;
```

**Edit:** With the amount of table contingencies, why not just go with temp tables for all datasets involved?:

```
SELECT W.ROW_ID
INTO #tempSplit_Segments
FROM table1 W
WHERE W.ERRORS IS NULL AND W.UserName = @userId

SELECT DISTINCT ROW_ID, AP
FROM #tempSplit_Segments 
WHERE LEN(AP) <> 3;

SELECT A.ROW_ID
INTO #tempTable
FROM #tempSplit_Segments A
  INNER JOIN table4 B ON A.ROW_ID = B.ROW_ID
    AND A.AP = B.AP
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tb Z ON A.ROW_ID = Z.ROW_ID
WHERE Z.AP IS NULL;
 
UPDATE W SET ERRORS = 'Error' 
FROM table5 W
  INNER JOIN tb T ON W.ROW_ID = T.ROW_ID
WHERE AP is not null;
```

Comment: I tried making CTE for the last select statement but it is not allowing me to do so because I have INTO clause inside it. I updated one line of code above.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to have it as a temp table? If you run it the way I have the code in the second example above, you would have access to it as a CTE under the alias `third_cte` (or whatever you wanted to name it to, `#tempTable`, etc). Usually I try to use either CTEs or temp tables exclusively, rather than mixing them together.

Comment: Actually, I am using that temp table out side of With clause block of statements. If I do not use it, I cannot use this CTE outside and I might be in the same issue as I have now while doing update statement..I hope it clears out. Thank you

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect how I would approach the problem given the constraints of the `#tempTable` you need to build outside of the CTE, that depends on a table constructed within the CTE.

Comment: Yeah you are correct but sorry is using CTE inside tb CTE. Just updated the code. Really sorry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if I've followed it right, this is the update you want to execute, right?

`UPDATE W SET ERRORS = 'Error' 
FROM table5 W
INNER JOIN tb T ON W.ROW_ID = T.ROW_ID
WHERE AP IS NOT NULL;`

For that to work, you need tb, which is a CTE... so add it:

`;WITH tb AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        ROW_ID, AP
    FROM 
        Split_Segments 
    WHERE 
        LEN(AP) <> 3

)
UPDATE W SET ERRORS = 'Error' 
FROM table5 W
INNER JOIN tb T ON W.ROW_ID = T.ROW_ID
WHERE AP IS NOT NULL;`

Now tb also need Split_Segments which is also a CTE, so that also needs to be included...

`;WITH Split_Segments AS 
(
    SELECT 
        W.ROW_ID
    FROM 
        table1 W
    WHERE
        W.ERRORS IS NULL AND W.UserName = @userId
),tb AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        ROW_ID, AP
    FROM 
        Split_Segments 
    WHERE 
        LEN(AP) <> 3

)
UPDATE W SET ERRORS = 'Error' 
FROM table5 W
INNER JOIN tb T ON W.ROW_ID = T.ROW_ID
WHERE AP IS NOT NULL;`

There... now it should work... there's nothing in the update that need the temp table or anything else other than the CTEs....

Comment: But I need temp table at the end which I have not shown here. However, but from the first CTE, tb, how it will be able to get the value of split_segments which you have defined later only. Thanks